# Can’t access Promise object

Tags: javascript, object, promise

```
console.log(TransactionDataPromise[0]);
```

logs the following object:

```
Promise {
  {
    blockHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockNumber: null,
    from: '0x88B837d3528Fb13192e0b7b1009632A8372d8c8a',
    gas: 1000000,
    gasPrice: '15000000000',
    hash: '0xa1d5a80b738504acb30663c7d7ae869c52ca5430738c679536f8dfb72e770610',
    input: '0x741dfb1e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b8bdb9785200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d',
    nonce: 12530,
    to: '0x6f9B3f0640Bf7358C87d1d7f2Df1A546Df0E8C08',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    value: '0',
    v: '0x2b',
    r: '0xcd46cea5babf84761ac4aaf7d9351264f51f82c0739829ad1d9a336d03a6900d',
    s: '0x61314be797bb7fcbf00bfeb6e34d318281cac58f665bdc26e38cf7e718d0abf6'
  }
}
```

However,

```
console.log(TransactionDataPromise[0].to);
```

shows `undefined`, whereas I expected `0x6f9B3f0640Bf7358C87d1d7f2Df1A546Df0E8C08`. How do I access this `to` property?

Comment: the word `Promise` suggests asynchrony so, what you see in the console isn't necessarily the current "state" of that object, it's the state when you inspect it in the console

Comment: does `console.log(typeof TransactionDataPromise[0].then)` produce `function` - if so, then `TransactionDataPromise[0].then(o => console.log(o.to))` should log what you expect - and, see the link in the above comment

Comment: try `TransactionDataPromise[0].then((data) => console.log(data))

Comment: @Geuis Or `.then(({to}) => console.log(to))` directly.

Comment: I have already "waited" for the data and have it, hence why i get the first output. 

fyi Other part of my code before i do the outputs: 

var allPromises2 = Promise.all([
 
 TransactionDataPromise[0]
]);


var sendPromise2 = allPromises2.then(function(results2){

Comment: @JaromandaX 
Indeed it produced `function`. However, the code you suggested didn't produce anything. :/

Comment: really? any errors in the console? what about `TransactionDataPromise[0].then(o => console.log(o))`

Comment: you seem to be faffing around with Promise.all, then another promise ... are you attempting to use so much indirection of the promise that you hope it will eventually turn synchronous?

Comment: @JaromandaX I was mistaken. The first solution indeed worked, it just had produced the expected result A LOT later. I struggle to understand why I can't directly access the Promised object's data which I obviously already have, proof `console.log(TransactionDataPromise[0]);`  
I would be more happy, however I will have to check all the `array TransactionDataPromise`. 
I guess you can submit your comment as a solution!

Comment: I use two Promises, because only after I get the first one (Ethereum Block) I am able to find the "to" Address over the asynch API I am using.

Comment: I found the solution. It is to get the result by `console.log(results2[0].to);` instead of calling the `console.log(TransactionDataPromise[0]);`